# How to use ExpressJS and Socket.io on a same port?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

In the third version of ExpressJS *express.createServer()* changed to *express()* this changes makes difficult to bind socket.io on a same port. Maybe somebody could find robust decision.

Now, this doesn't work:

```
var express = require('express')
, app = express.createServer()
, io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
```

My current workflow: https://gist.github.com/3596852

Comment: I'd be interested in that as well. Socket.io's readme got updated to match Express 3.0 (see https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io#express-3x), but that doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It's described on the [socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io#express-3x) github page (as [@Golo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235406/how-to-use-expressjs-and-socket-io-on-a-same-port#comment16398322_12235406) stated in your comment):

```
var app = express()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = io.listen(server);

server.listen(80);
```

This works, I have it running.

Probably what Golo have forgotten is to change the listen from `app.listen(80)` to `server.listen(80)`. I've struggled with this too until I realised my stupid mistake.

Comment: yes changing `app.listen` to `server.listen` fixed it for me too!

Comment: This solution still works for current Express. Check [this](http://docker.lhsm.com.br/60aaaeec-d582-461b-8bd6-ebe2b63dfd50) this live example.

Comment: This worked for me in express: 4.16.3, socket.io: 2.1.1.

Answer (score 2):

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)

app.start = app.listen = function(){
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments)
}

app.start(8080)
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/3620800 check out this gist, its with working body parser example.