# Socket and Server Listening on the Same Port?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'd like both the socket and the server to listen on port 443. Problem is when I do it, I get a warning EADDRINUSE. Is there a workaround to make both socket and server listen on the same port?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use ExpressJS and Socket.io on a same port?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235406/how-to-use-expressjs-and-socket-io-on-a-same-port)

Answer (score -1):

i don't know what are you doing in ur code but make clear that only server is listening on any port and we have to bind express.js and socket.io on that server, means they all are on same port..
please go throw this code:

```
    var express=require('express');
    var app = express();
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
    app.listen(8000)'
```