# GraphQLServer + Socket-io on same port

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, socket.io, apollo

I have a working project with GraphQLServer serving my react app from port 4000 and socket-io listening on port 5000.

**I'm trying to deploy to heroku so I need them to be on the same port** (process.env.PORT), but I can't figure out how to do it with GraphQLServer.

[This is how to do it with express + socket-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235406/how-to-use-expressjs-and-socket-io-on-a-same-port)

[This is the start script for GraphQLServer](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-yoga#startoptions-options-callback-options-options--void----null-promisevoid)

[Gist with my current code is here](https://gist.github.com/baconcheese113/edbc738379a53792dd3cce0f4c8ad5ba#file-server-index-js)

Relevant code:

```js
import server from './server';
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';

const http = require('http').Server(server.express);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
require('./socket')(io);

server.express.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../client/build')));
server.express.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../client/build', 'index.html'));
});

// Socket-io listener
http.listen({
    port: process.env.PORT || 5000
  }, () =>
  console.log('listening on port ' + process.env.PORT || 5000)
);

// GraphQL and app listener
server.start({
    cors: {
      credentials: true,
      origin: '/'
    }
    // port: process.env.PORT || 4000
  },
  () => {
    console.log('The server is up!');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't get any input from devs of [graphql-yoga](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-yoga), so asked on the [prisma slack](https://prisma.slack.com) and was advised to use [apollo-server-express](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/tree/master/packages/apollo-server-express) instead.

The main changes I noticed switching to ApolloServer were:

1. It passes `{ req, res }` instead of `{ request, response }`
2. You need to import your schema with [graphql-import](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-import) ex: `typeDefs: importSchema('./src/schema.graphql')`

**First I create an express app and httpServer for socket-io and tell io to listen to the httpServer instantiated with app**:

```js
const app = express();
const httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer);
require('./socket')(io); // my io.on('connection', socket => {}) function taking io as param
io.listen(httpServer);
```

**Then i apply all middleware and set routes with app**:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../client/build')));
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../client/build', 'index.html'));
  });
} else {
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../client/public', 'index.html'));
  });
}

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.cookies || !req.cookies.token) {
    return next();
  }
  const { token } = req.cookies;
  if (token) {
    console.log(process.env.PORT);
    const { userId } = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    // Put the userId onto the req for future requests to access
    req.userId = userId;
  }
  next();
});
```

**Finally (using ApolloServer 2) I apply the app as middleware to ApolloServer and tell the httpServer to listen**:

```js
import server from './server' // my ApolloServer

server.applyMiddleware({
  app,
  path: '/graphql',
  cors: {
    credentials: true,
    origin: process.env.DOMAIN_FULL + ':' + process.env.PORT || '3000'
  }
});

httpServer.listen({
    port: process.env.PORT || 4000
  },
  () => console.log(`Server is running on ${server.graphqlPath}`)
);
```

Make sure with the client you're instancing using io() without params, and your ApolloClient uri is `'/graphql'`