# Port 3000 already in use. Nodejs, Socket,IO

Tags: node.js, socket.io, port

**No other process runs on port 3000 except this**

Here's the part of a program

```
const port = process.env.port || 3000;

app.listen((port), () => console.log(`listening to port ${port}`));

const io = require("socket.io")(port) //Here's the problem.
```

Problem appears when I add port 3000

**If I manually write some other port like 4000. It works**

Shall I create another port for socket.io?

In case of port 3000

**The error looks like this**

```
listening to port 3000
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000

Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1345:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node / Express: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use - Kill server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone it doesn't. I think we can't run socket.io and express server on same port

Comment: socket.io and express can share the same server so can run on the same port

Comment: lmgtfy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235406/how-to-use-expressjs-and-socket-io-on-a-same-port

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I think it's unresolved for now. nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal try this to find the active port:

**Windows**

```
netstat -ano | findstr :3000
```

**Mac/Linux**

```
lsof -iTCP:3000 -sTCP:LISTEN
```

Then kill using the PID:

```
kill <PID>
```

or this if the above doesn't work

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

Comment: isof is unrecognized to the terminal. i use windows

Comment: Try ```netstat -ano | findstr :3000``` instead.

Comment: 3000 is only running on this project.

Answer (score 0):

It means that there is a process that uses 3000 port, try to kill that process and start the application again.

Comment: this is a project and it all runs on 3000

Comment: Your project may still be running in the background by the time when you want to start it again.